# R: log-log model with log intercept

Tags: r, statistics

For a homework task, I need to fit this log-to-log model into R: log(Y) = log(b0)+ b1*log(x). I managed to figure out the following:

```
lm(log(y) ~ log(x))
```

But now, how do I specify that the intercept should also be a logarithm?